# Did you talk yet? or Have you talked yet?

Tags: meaning, past-tense, present-perfect

Is this sentence correct:

"Did you talk to him yet?"

based on the English I've learn so far I would say sth like this in situation like this:

"Have you talked to him yet?"

What's the difference?

Comment: In most cases either one is fine.  There is a slight difference in meaning, but the difference is mainly just one of "personal choice".  The second option is perhaps a bit more formal.

Comment: The first example would be better without the **yet** – "Did you talk to him?" There is a difference in tenses.

Comment: They're both fine, and it doesn't make any difference which one you use. In fact, nobody will notice which one you use, or remember it a minute later.

Comment: The first one would, I believe, be fine in American English, but the second is much more usual in British English.

Answer (score 1):

ll of the option s mentioned in the question are fine, and the differences in meaning are small and subtle.

> Did you talk to him yet?

Perfectly straightforward. Implies that if "you"  have not **yet** talked to him, you should do so.

> Have you talked to him yet?

Slightly more formal. Essentially the same meaning, with teh same implication.

> Did you talk to him?

No implication, a straight question

> Have you talked to him

The above has pretty much identical meaning to the one before, again no implication.

All four versions are grammatical and idiomatic. Any may be used freely.